# SQL 5.1 Trigger syntax error

Tags: mysql, triggers, syntax-error

I have this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `VerficiaDispon` BEFORE INSERT ON `ordini` 
FOR EACH
ROW 
BEGIN 
DECLARE temp INT

SET temp = (SELECT disponibili FROM motoinstock 
            WHERE Moto = new.Moto_Comprata 
                AND Concessionario = new.Concessionario_Vendita);

IF temp = 0 OR temp IS NULL THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Moto non disponibile';

END IF ;

SELECT acquisti
INTO temp
FROM clienticoncessionari
WHERE cliente = new.Cod_Cliente
AND concessionario = new.Concessionario_Vendita;

IF temp %2 =1 THEN SET new.Prezzo_Vendita = ( new.Prezzo_Vendita * 0.9 ) ;

END IF ;

END;
```

And i cant make it work in sql 5.1. It gives me an error on line 7. I tried select X into temp, set temp=(...), but nothing seems to work.
I cant find the sintax error, can someone plese help me? It must be sql 5.1

Comment: i know it should be raise_application_error(8-2061,'derp'); instead of SIGNAL SQLSTATE...

Comment: try adding `delimiter $$` at the begging and `$$` to the last end, and change the delimiter again `delimiter ;`

Comment: you mean like this?
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER `VerficiaDispon` BEFORE INSERT ON `ordini` 
FOR EACH
ROW 
BEGIN 
DECLARE temp INT

SET temp = (SELECT disponibili FROM motoinstock WHERE Moto = new.Moto_Comprata AND Concessionario = new.Concessionario_Vendita;)$$

? still wont work.
i'm sorry if it's not like you meant, i'm not skilled in sql

Answer (score 0):

```
Delimiter $$

CREATE TRIGGER `VerficiaDispon` BEFORE INSERT ON `ordini` 
FOR EACH
ROW 
BEGIN 
DECLARE temp INT

SET temp = (SELECT disponibili FROM motoinstock 
            WHERE Moto = new.Moto_Comprata 
                AND Concessionario = new.Concessionario_Vendita);

IF temp = 0 OR temp IS NULL THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Moto non disponibile';

END IF ;

SELECT acquisti
INTO temp
FROM clienticoncessionari
WHERE cliente = new.Cod_Cliente
AND concessionario = new.Concessionario_Vendita;

IF temp %2 =1 THEN SET new.Prezzo_Vendita = ( new.Prezzo_Vendita * 0.9 ) ;

END IF ;

END
$$

Delimiter ;
```

Comment: i keep gettin the same error:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET temp = (SELECT disponibili FROM motoinstock WHERE Moto = new.M' at line 7

Answer (score 0):

The SIGNAL statement is only available in MySQL 5.5.

Using SIGNAL in a trigger in 5.1 will cause a syntax error, because MySQL does not know about this statement.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i've solved almost every problem.
Now the code is this:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER `VerficiaDispon` BEFORE INSERT ON `ordini` 
FOR EACH
ROW 
BEGIN 

DECLARE temp integer;
SET temp = (SELECT disponibili FROM motoinstock 
            WHERE Moto = new.Moto_Comprata 
                AND Concessionario = new.Concessionario_Vendita);

IF temp=0 OR temp=NULL THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'NA');


SET temp = ( SELECT acquisti FROM clienticoncessionari 
             WHERE cliente = new.Cod_Cliente
              AND concessionario = new.Concessionario_Vendita);

IF temp %2 =1 THEN SET new.Prezzo_Vendita = ( new.Prezzo_Vendita * 0.9 ) ;

END IF ;


END
delimiter ;
```

Now my problem is on the IF. I cant get to raise an error, for some reason RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR wont work. 
All the rest is good. Any ideas on how to handle the error?